# Open Graph insights by story

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

Is it possible to get impression count by open graph story? Current insights show Feed, Ticker and Timeline impressions by action.

I am more interested by story and not action. Is this possible? I tried different FQL tables and graph API with no luck.